# Why is setContent{} being called twice?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've recently started my first project using Jetpack Compose (with minimal Android dev experience).
For checking performance, I logged each call to any function / composable, with some unexpected behavior at startup or orientation change (but without further interacting with the app):
[image: Log]

I do understand oncreate / super being called (again, in case of orientation change), but why is it that setContent {} is being called twice?

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.v(tag, "oncreate")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.v(tag, "oncreatesuper")
    setContent {
        Log.v(tag, "setting content")
        Content()
    }
}
```

and then

```
  @Composable
private fun Content() {
    val arrayOfNodes = rememberSaveable { mutableListOf<Wurzel>() }
    val toggleSizeInputDialog = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    (...some more...)
    val currentConfig = LocalConfiguration.current
    val title = stringResource(id = R.string.title)
    Log.v(tag, "recomposing content")

    MyTheme {
        when (currentConfig.orientation) {
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> {
                Scaffold(...........)
```

My project is far to small to see any perfomance issues, however I'd like to find out the reason for this behavior for future reference or whether I severely misunderstood the compose architecture.

Answer (score 2):

`setComponent()` is not being called twice, but the composable function you pass in it is. It just seems like some event causes recomposition of the `content` composable.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue recently and it has something to do with running Jetpack compose apps from the IDE. When I ran my app from the device launcher icon it only called set content once. Also, this issue only occurred when I ran the app using the run button and not when run using the debug button. This is not a recompose issue as you can see from the simple app I used to test this issue. It's the setContent that is the issue and not the actual content of my composable that caused the problem. The problem persisted until I restarted Android Studio and then it magically stopped happening.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            println("MainActivity: setContent")
            AppTheme {
                Text("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I figured it out. It only happens after you open the on-device layout inspector. Once you open it setContent is called anywhere from 2 to 4 times when the app starts. If you close the layout inspector, this will keep happening and the only way to stop it is by restarting Android Studio.